# Replacing Fragment does not change properly

Tags: android, android-fragments

The issue occurs when I attempt to switch from the Second Fragment to the First Fragment. I am using ActionBar Option Menu Icons to navigate back and forth between the different fragments.

Each fragment has its own menu that is associated with the individual option menu items. I cannot seem to figure out why I am able to transition from one the First Fragment to the Second Fragment, but am unable to do the reverse.

**Does anything in my code stand out that would disable me from being able to navigate back to the previous fragment?**

I was able to switch between the fragments without any issues in the past, but after I incorporated these option menu items to do the navigation, it stopped working.

**Starting Fragment**

```
public class SearchFragmentActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search_fragment,
            container, false);

    btnBasketball = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnBasketball);
    btnBasketball.setOnClickListener(this);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_search_event, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_more:
        // do something with a dropdown
        break;

    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btnBasketball:

        changeFragment("Basketball");

        break;
    }

}

public void changeFragment(String sportName) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("SPORTNAME", sportName);

    Fragment fragment = new SearchDetailsFragmentActivity();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.cell_left_in,
            R.anim.cell_right_out);
    transaction.replace(R.id.searchFragment, fragment);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

}

**Second Fragment**

```
public class SearchDetailsFragmentActivity extends Fragment {

TextView tvSportsName;
GridView gView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search_details_fragment,
            container, false);

    String sportsName = getArguments().getString("SPORTNAME");

    tvSportsName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSportsName);
    tvSportsName.setText(sportsName);

    // SportAdapter sAdapter = new SportAdapter(getActivity(), lstSports);

    gView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridViewSearch);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_search_details_event, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_cancel:

        changeFragment();
        break;

    }
    return true;
}

public void changeFragment() {

    Fragment fragment = new SearchFragmentActivity();

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.cell_left_in,
            R.anim.cell_right_out);
    transaction.replace(R.id.searchDetailsFragment, fragment);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

}

**Options Menu associated with Second Fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_content_remove"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

**UPDATES**

These changes allow me to navigate backwards from the SearchDetailsFragmentActivity >> SearchFragmentActivity using the SoftKey Back Button.

**Changes  to the changeFragment() method inside SearchDetailsFragmentActivity**

```
    public void changeFragment() {

    Fragment fragment = new SearchFragmentActivity();

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    //FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    //transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.cell_left_in,
            //R.anim.cell_right_out);
    //transaction.replace(R.id.searchDetailsFragment, fragment);

    //transaction.commit();
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```

**inside the SearchFragmentActivity**

```
public void changeFragment(String sportName) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("SPORTNAME", sportName);

    Fragment fragment = new SearchDetailsFragmentActivity();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.cell_left_in,
            R.anim.cell_right_out);
    transaction.replace(R.id.searchFragment, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I placed a Log.e inside the OnOptionItemSelected() to see if the button was even firing properly and it appears as if it is not. There is nothing that is getting logged.

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_cancel:
        Log.e("IS THIS WORKING", "THIS IS WORKING");   <<< NOT FIRING
        changeFragment();
        break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When replacing a fragment, you need to indicate whether or not that transaction is reversable (i.e. whether or not it goes onto the backstack). For the first fragment transaction, you usually won't want to do this (wouldn't want to pop to an empty view). For fragment replacements, you want to specify `addToBackStack()` with an optional tag (which can be later used with `popBackStack(String)`).

For example, in between these lines:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.searchDetailsFragment, fragment);

transaction.commit();
```

add:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.searchDetailsFragment, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: I implemented these changes and it does not do anything when trying to return to the previous fragment. The First Fragment is hosted with in a tab activity. The solution that was provided allows me to use the soft key back button to go back to the First Fragment.

I will update the question with what is happening.

Comment: I found another issue, it does not seem like the OnOptionsItemSelected is firing properly. I included a log and it doesn't do anything. I will update this as well.